# LaTeX Interactive Guide

Tags: mathematics, guide

Does anyone have the link of this cool website I remember which was an interactive guide to writing mathematics in LaTeX? It would take you through the basics like grouping elements, spacings, super/sub-scripts, symbols, etc. I don't remember the website link. If someone knows, please let me know. I hope this is a valid question.

Comment: https://www.learnlatex.org/ ?

Comment: I suggest trying to google "latex online equation editor" and see if the results include what you mean.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/

Comment: Oh well... I found it a few days ago... Was talking about https://math-on-quora.surge.sh/ this! Thanks for all the help everyone 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean **"visualFAQ – A Visual LATEX FAQ"**, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/visualfaq.

[image]

[image]

---

### Update

Wild guess :): https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php

[image]

Comment: Interesting... but sadly I do not mean this. It was a web interface, with input and real time output showing in front of you. Mainly about mathematical formulae as I described above... I have asked many people now and none could tell... now, maybe I'm not able to describe properly, or otherwise it doesn't exist and I just dreamt about it (which would be embarassing...)

Comment: @n11 See update :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Could you perhaps be thinking of [**TeXnique**](https://texnique.xyz/)?

[image: This is an animated GIF of me playing TeXnique with an identity from Pascal's triangle. In particular, the sum of i choose r from i equal to r to i equal to n, is equal to n plus one choose r plus one.]

It’s not so much didactive as it is interactive—it doesn’t teach you the basics, but it does have real-time interactions which may be similar to what you’re looking for.

Comment: Very cool site. Some of the more complex examples are hard to get exactly right, and there doesn't seem to be a way to show the intended markup.